# How can I use DATE_FORMAT() with year and month

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Original source:

```php
public function getChargeData($company_id,$month)
{
    $sql = "select * from foo_records where DATE_FORMAT(bar_date,'%m')  = $month";
    $chargeList = \DB::select($sql);
    return $chargeList;
}
```

This function could fetch a whole month.

However, it does not filter by year; it should filter by year because it is also selecting records for the same month in 2022.

I try making a function like this. But It didn't work. No record was not fetched:

```php
public function getData($year,$month)
{
    $sql = "select * from foo_records where DATE_FORMAT(bar_date,'%Y'-'%m')  = ".$year."-".$month;
}
```

The bar_date column is DATETIME type:

```
2021-08-13 00:00:00
2021-08-14 00:00:00
2021-08-20 00:00:00
2021-08-25 00:00:00
2021-08-31 00:00:00
2021-09-01 00:00:00
2021-09-03 00:00:00
2021-09-15 00:00:00
2021-09-25 00:00:00
```

When $year = 2021, $month = 08 the expected result would be:

```
2021-08-13 00:00:00
2021-08-14 00:00:00
2021-08-20 00:00:00
2021-08-25 00:00:00
2021-08-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: Did you do anything other than create a string variable in PHP. You have to get the database to run that query and then fetch the resultset. There is no magic involved

Comment: Please start by reading the [PHP Manual for the PDO Database extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo) It comes complete with examples and all sorts of help.  How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` wants a string value as second parameter. You are trying to pass it a math expression for some reason. But I don't know what you expect the result of "the text `%Y` minus the text `%m`" to be, and the database probably doesn't either.

Comment: You are probably using MySQL. `'%Y'-'%m'` should result in an error, because you cannot subtract a string from another. A good DBMS in this aspect would issue an error message explaining this. MySQL, however, converts the strings to numbers, defaulting to 0, as the strings don't contain numbers. Thus you get 0 - 0 = 0. The DBMS should optimally tell you now that you are calling `DATE_FORMAT` with an invalid format string (0 gets converted to '0'), but well, MySQL considers this valid; it assumes you want a constant '0' regardless of the bar_date value.

Comment: For what it's worth, you'll get better performance if you just calculate start and end date in PHP and retrieve the exact range in SQL because you don't need to retrieve and manipulate every row in the table. That also allows to create an index on the column.

Answer (score 1):

The query being sent to server would look like:

```sql
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(bar_date,'%Y'-'%m') = 2021-01
```

which obviously won't work as `'%Y'-'%m'` results in 0 and `2021-01` is 2020. Instead of asking you to place the `'` in the correct place, I propose this:

```
WHERE bar_date >= '2021-06-01'
AND   bar_date <  '2021-06-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

where `2021` and `06` are your `$year` and `$month` variables and `-01` and `+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH` are hard-coded.

Comment: @flow Stack: Salman A proposes this expression in order not to invoke a function on `bar_date` and thus enabling the DBMS to use an index on that column if available.